# How to halt Rails controller action from a before filter and respond with 422 unprocessable entity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method ("before filter") in my Rails controller that needs to respond with a 422 status code if some params are missing. How can I do this from within a before filter?

```
class FoobarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_parent

  def create
    if @parent.foobar.save
      render @parent.foobar, status: :created
    else
      render @parent.foobar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def find_parent
    if params[:parent_id]
      @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
    elsif params[:foobar_id]
      @parent = Foobar.find(params[:foobar_id])
    else
      raise 'Missing parent ID param' # TODO: respond with 422 status instead of 500
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`:status` option of `render` method will do the trick:

```
render status: 422
```

or

```
render status: :unprocessable_entity
```

More info can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option).

Also as @MaxWilliams noted in the comment, in complicated code, like yours, it's a good practice to use `return` with `render` statement:

```
render(status:422) and return
```

Comment: I would do `render(status: 422) and return` to make sure it doesn't go on to do anything else.

Comment: hmm...maybe I was missing the return because I tried calling `render` but it continued through the controller action

Comment: @Andrew I don't think so. Once "filter" is done it should not continue if rendered.

Comment: Maybe I was using a private method at the time when I tried it.